# Customize arguments in spring bean autowired constructor, before instantiation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

What I need to achieve is the same behaviour as `@RequestParam("foo")` but in the constructor of a `REQUEST` scoped bean, where other constructor arguments would be autowired normally.

I would like to have a request parameter injected in the constructor as if it were a normal bean, but obviously without actually been a spring bean.

Example:

```
@Component
@RequestScope
public class RequestBean {    
    private final String filter;
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public RequestBean(@Param("filter") String filter, UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.filter = filter;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }
    ...
}
```

I tried using a BeanFactoryPostProcessor but the value I need to inject have to be obtained at request time, not at bean definition time.

```
public class MyBeanFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {

        Stream.of(beanFactory.getBeanDefinitionNames())
                .map(name -> beanFactory.getBeanDefinition(name))
                .filter(def -> "request".equals(def.getScope()))
                .forEach(beanDefinition -> {
                    try {
                        System.out.println(beanDefinition);

                        for (Constructor<?> constructor : Class.forName(beanDefinition.getBeanClassName()).getConstructors()) {
                            for (Parameter parameter : constructor.getParameters()) {
                                Param param = parameter.getAnnotation(Param.class);
                                if(param != null) {
                                    String paramName = param.value(); // filter
                                    Object requestParameterValue = "request.getParameter('" + paramName + "')"; // bean creation time evaluated argument

                                    beanDefinition.getConstructorArgumentValues().addGenericArgumentValue(
                                        new ConstructorArgumentValues.ValueHolder(requestParameterValue, parameter.getType().getName(), parameter.getName())
                                    );      
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        // whatever
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

For a request to `/index?filter=blue` I would expect "blue" and userRepository been autowired.

If I try with fixed values, it works perfectly, the value and the other bean are autowired normally.

I cannot use `BeanPostProcessor` because the values have to be acquired before instantiation (contructor injection)

Comment: Can't you just inject the HttpServletRequest and get the param out of it?

Comment: No, I can't. There isn't any request to inject in the BeanFactoryPostProcessor because this piece of code is executed at bean registration time.

Comment: I meant to inject the request in the RequestBean (and to forget completely about the post processor).

Comment: In that case I could, but I want to leave the beans as simple as possible. 
I don't feel confortable repeating the same lines over and over.
Where possible, I prefer plain java to classes knowing about the request object.
Easier to test, easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found out a way to achieve what I want.

I defined a `REQUEST` scoped to ease the process of getting and converting a request parameter.
This bean will be called at creation time thanks to an expression (SprEL) registered in the BeanFactoryPostProcessor.
The expression will be evaluated and the returned value injected in the annotated parameter.

This adds the dynamic expression to the constructor parameter:

```
String name = param.value();
TypedStringValue dynamicValue = new TypedStringValue("#{@myBean.getParameter('"+name+"')}");
beanDefinition.getConstructorArgumentValues().addIndexedArgumentValue(index, dynamicValue, constructorParameter.getType().getName());
```

And this is the bean called by the expression before the annotated bean instantiation:

```
@Component
@RequestScope
class MyBean {
    final HttpServletRequest request;

    public MyBean(HttpServletRequest request) {
        this.request = request;
    }        

    public String getParameter(String name){
        // do something 
        return request.getParameter(name);
    }
}
```